# passport-linkedin-oauth2 showing error: You need to pass the "redirect_uri" parameter? Am I missing a the redirect_uri somewhere?

Tags: javascript, next.js, passport.js, linkedin-api, passport-linkedin

When I get to this page -> `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&scope=r_emailddress%20r_liteprofile&state=[state]&client_id=[client_id]`

I get the error of Error: You need to pass the redirect_uri parameter.

Context: Using NextJS and passport for login
The linkedin strat is below:

```
passport.use(
  new LinkedinStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackurl: "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/linkedin/callback",
      scope: ["r_emailddress", "r_liteprofile"],
      state: true,
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      console.log(profile);
    }
  )
);
```

I have added the redirect uri in the linkedin developer settings as well

I have absolutely no clue where else i need to add the redirect uri other than linkedin developer settings and inside the linkedin strat above

Comment: Did you use `passport.authenticate('linkedin')` to get this login URL, or ...?

Comment: Yes, they are added before the request functions inside the get requests

Comment: Fyi, your scope of "r_emailaddress" is misspelled in your code.